# HTML5/CSS: Paragraph words printed below each other instead of next to each other

Tags: html, css

like the title describes; my text in paragraph tags are displaying below each other instead of next to each other. I'm new to HTML and CSS so excuse me if I asked a dumb question.

Here's a picture:
[image]

CSS & HTML code:

```css
.Display_shit p {
    color: White !important;
    margin-right: 95% !important;
    margin-left: 5% !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
}
.Display_shit .FP-Title p {
    font-size: 40px !important;
    top: 225px !important;
}
.Display_shit .FP-Text p {
    font-size: 30px;
    top: 300px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav a {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
#BackgroundVid {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#rcorners1 {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 200px;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
#CornerLeftUpLW {
    position: fixed;
    left: 15px;
    top: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
#CornerRightDownLW {
    position: fixed;
    left: 335px;
    top: 45px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
#TextBackground {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 150px;
    height: 2000px;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.nav {
    height: 55px;
    background-color: black;
    position: unset;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: left;
    /*text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px rgb(133, 135, 255);*/
}
.nav a{
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
}
.nav ul{
    position: fixed;
    top: -15px;
    right: 20px;
}
.nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav ul li a{
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: myFirstFont;
            src: url(./Ultra.otf);
        }
    </style>
    <title>johndoe.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--Background vid-->
    <video autoplay muted loop id="BackgroundVid">
        <source src="./img/4k background footage.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <!--Text stuff-->
    <div id="rcorners1">
        <div class="Display_shit">
            <div class="FP-Title">
                <p>Title text go brrr</p>
            </div>
            <div class="FP-Text">
                <p>Why am I displayed like this</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <div class="nav">
        <div><a href="./index.html">John Doe</a></div>
        <img src="./img/CornerLeftUp.png" id="CornerLeftUpLW">
        <img src="./img/CornerRightDown.png" id="CornerRightDownLW">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="./about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And now I have to milk this text so that I can post it. Feel free to leave to opinions on the design since I'm new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove property margin-right 95% for paragraph